# gapi.client is undefined -- firefox add-on sdk

Tags: javascript, firefox, google-api, google-plus, firefox-addon-sdk

Following these instructions: https://developers.google.com/+/web/api/javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  (function() {
    var po = document.createElement('script'); po.type = 'text/javascript'; po.async = true;
    po.src = 'https://apis.google.com/js/client:plusone.js?onload=signin';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(po, s);
  })();
</script>
```

Inserted before the  tag...

The gapi object that is available inside the signout() callback does not include gapi.client .. in fact, I am getting gapi.client is undefined as a JS error.

I cannot call gapi.client.load('drive', 'v2', callback) since the client property is undefined.

This issue is only when using Firefox Add-on SDK and using cfx run to open a browser with the add-on I am developing being a sidebar element.

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong? Can provide more information if necessary!

Comment: If I run the html locally in firefox, it works fine and gapi.client is defined. If I do it as an add-on with cfx run, gapi.client is undefined.